# How can I manipulate nvd3 Horizontal Multi-Bar Chart values

Tags: nvd3.js

I am using nvd3.js and multiBarHorizontal http://nvd3.org/ghpages/multiBarHorizontal.html
I want to change the bars' reference on the x-axis to another value , 
for instance a value of 10 should be represented 10 out of 50.

value  ----------
 x-axis --------------------------------------------------
I really don't know where to start from.

Comment: Did the answer work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question properly you are looking at something like this I suppose -

```
chart.xAxis.tickFormat(function(d) {
    return d + '/50'
});
```

Hope it helps.